# Getting data from mongo using meteor react

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am just getting started with my project using Meteor/React.

**In my "Customer.jsx"**

```
Customer = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            //customer: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        },
        getInitialState: function () {
            return { customers: [] };
        },
        mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
        deleteThisCustomer(){
            Meteor.call("removeCustomer", this.props.customer._id);
        },
        getMeteorData() {
            let query = {};
            //query = {checked: {$ne: true}};
            return {
                customers: Customers.find(query, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
            };
        },
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Find the text field via the React ref
            var data = {};
            data['first_name']= ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.customerFirstName).value.trim();
            data['last_name'] = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.customerFirstName).value.trim();

            console.log(data);
            Meteor.call("addCustomer", data);

            // Clear form
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.customerFirstName).value = "";
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.customerLastName).value = "";
        },
        renderCustomers() {
            return this.data.customers.map((customer) => {

                return <Customer
                    key={customer._id}
                    customer={customer.first_name}
                    />

            });
        },
        singleCustomer(){
            return(
                <li className="customerClassName">
                    <button className="delete" onClick={this.deleteThisCustomer}>
                        &times;
                    </button>

                    <label>Here{ this.props.customer }</label>
                </li>
            );
        },
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Add new Customer</h1>
                        <form role="form" className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="customerFirstName" placeholder="First Name." />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="customerLastName" placeholder="Last Name." />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Add Customer</button>
                        </form>
                    </header>

                    <ul>
                        {this.singleCustomer()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

I keep getting an errors of all sorts every time I try to add first_name or last_name. Matter of fact I think that the whole order and structure of my render() is a nightmare.

Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Which errors are you getting? For starters, `this.refs.*` references the DOM nodes themselves as of v0.14.

Comment: first_name is not a recognized function

Comment: I don't see it being called anywhere. Try to narrow it down by gradually creating a new component or removing stuff from the existing one. You are rendering a `Customer` from within `Customer` in the `renderCustomers`. You may want to figure out which components you need and "componentize" your layout accordingly.

Comment: How can I render the customer info properly?
I need the first and last name.

Comment: It seems like you are creating a customer list, so it makes sense to create components for `CustomerList` and `Customer`. This will make the logic clearer and simpler.

Comment: MasterAM I totally agree with you, yet I am just not sure how. Any hits would be appreciated.

Comment: The [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) are good places to get started. They show the basics of the React API and component composition basics.